# Setting interval in Evernote Android-jobs for less than 15 minutes

Tags: android, evernote, android-job

I am using [Evernote Android Jobs](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library to schedule task on my Android **8.1.0**. The default minimum interval of periodic jobs is 15 minutes which is making debugging time-consuming. I found an [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-job-scheduling-with-android-job-4a2c020b9742) which says that we can use

```
    JobManager.instance().getConfig().setAllowSmallerIntervalsForMarshmallow(true);
```

for shorter intervals in debugging but I am  getting a squiggly line under getConfig() when I am using this.
How to reduce the interval time?

Android-jobs version **1.2.6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method **setAllowSmallerIntervalsForMarshmallow(true)** is deprecated and no longer in use in the library version **1.2.6** .We can use the following code to start the jobs.

NOTE: This should only be used for debugging and not in production.

```
    private void runJobImmediately() {
    new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
        .startNow()
        .build()
        .schedule();
   }
```